# Typo3 8.7 Fluid renders empty, if I put the extension into the static templates, why?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I create an extension in Typo3 8.7. The Folder `Configuration/TypoScript/` have two files `constants.ts` and `setup.ts`. My Extension works, the Fluid Templates `Resources/Private/Templates/EXT/List.html` rendered correct.

Now I insert my extension into the field `Include static (from extension)` on root page and now the fluid template rendered empty. Why? I only insert this code in setup.ts:

```
plugin.tx_EXT_PLUGIN {
    view {
        templateRootPaths.0 = EXT:EXT_PLUGIN/Resources/Private/Templates/
        partialRootPaths.0 = EXT:EXT_PLUGIN/Resources/Private/Partials/
        layoutRootPaths.0 = EXT:EXT_PLUGIN/Resources/Private/Layouts/
    }
}
```

No error message displayed. Nothing. But Why?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you use the Typoscript-Object-Browser to check the paths?

Comment: If the paths are checked in Ts backend: Template->object browser, it may be you need to clear cache with install tool?

Comment: The path are correct! I cleared the Cache over install Tool. Nothing helps

Comment: And if you put the config in constants.ts, instead of setup.ts? Hope that works

Comment: You should not overwrite the ...Paths.0 - use templateRootPaths.10 to overwrite the existing templates with yours.

Comment: I can use any number. And for the initial Template i use everytime 0. For test I change it to 10, but this doesn't solve the problem.